# Update Pannel Trigger not working

Tags: asp.net, updatepanel

I have this html that contains a `UpdatePanel` and a `Button`, I would like update my User Control(that have a UpdatePanel too) when `Button` click 
I get this error: **A control with ID 'btnSubmit' could not be found for the trigger in UpdatePanel** when page load.

```
<asp:Content ID="Content1" ContentPlaceHolderID="content" runat="server">

        <asp:UpdatePanel runat="server" ID="updatePanelMyUC" UpdateMode="Conditional" ChildrenAsTriggers="false">

            <ContentTemplate>
                <uc1:myUserControl runat="server" ID="myUserControlID"/>
            </ContentTemplate>

            <Triggers>
                <asp:AsyncPostBackTrigger ControlID="btnSubmit" EventName="Click" />
            </Triggers>
        </asp:UpdatePanel>


    </asp:Content>

    <asp:Content ID="Content2" ContentPlaceHolderID="rightcolumn" runat="server">
        <asp:ImageButton ID="btnSubmit" ImageUrl="../../Resources/btnSubmit.png" runat="server" OnClick="btnSubmit_Click" />
    </asp:Content>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your `btnSubmit` is outside the `UpdatePanel`. 
Trigger of the `UpdatePanel` must be inside the `ContentTemplate` of the said `UpdatePanel`.

```
<asp:Content ID="Content1" ContentPlaceHolderID="content" runat="server">

    <asp:UpdatePanel runat="server" ID="updatePanelMyUC" UpdateMode="Conditional" ChildrenAsTriggers="false">

        <ContentTemplate>
            <uc1:myUserControl runat="server" ID="myUserControlID"/>
            <asp:ImageButton ID="btnSubmit" ImageUrl="../../Resources/btnSubmit.png" runat="server" OnClick="btnSubmit_Click" />
        </ContentTemplate>

        <Triggers>
            <asp:AsyncPostBackTrigger ControlID="btnSubmit" EventName="Click" />
        </Triggers>
    </asp:UpdatePanel>


</asp:Content>

<asp:Content ID="Content2" ContentPlaceHolderID="rightcolumn" runat="server">
</asp:Content>
```

Comment: But I have a custom CSS for each `Content`, have any way to perform `UpdatePanel` with btnSubmit outside the UpdatePanel?

Comment: Remove the <Triggers> tag then on the code of your btnSubmit, put updatePanelMyUC.Update()

Comment: It will only update the content inside that specific `UpdatePanel`. Now if your `UserControl` contains what you call the 'all page' then it's a different story.

Comment: Work fine for me